# Why does the button on my site work locally but changes position & formatting when i upload online?

Tags: html, css, button, formatting, mailchimp

I embedded a form from MailChimp & i tried to customise the button with CSS.It works when i view locally on my laptop but changes position & clears all formatting when i upload to github.  PLEASE HELP!!! I have tried everything. See images & my code below for reference.

Image 1 - Local:

[image]

Image 2 - Online:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title></title>
    <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <style type="text/css">
                #mc_embed_signup{clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
                /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
                We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
            </style>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div class="box" id="text">

            <P>THE BIGGEST TECH EVENT OF THE YEAR</P>

        </div>



        <div class="box">

            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

            <div id="mc_embed_signup">

                <form action="https://website.us19.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=85ff9e186cc7716994921bf48&amp;id=fd58e3c77c" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">


                        <div class="clear">

                            <button class="button" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">Press Here</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>

            <!--End mc_embed_signup-->


        </div>



    </div>


</body>
</html>



html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.box {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#text p {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.box button {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px; 
    height: 40px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.box button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
```